# Dancing in the vineyards on yom kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, shidduchim-dating, dance, masechet-taanis

The gemoro end Taanis says that twice a year the girls went dancing in the vineyards. Maybe that explains a previous post of mine why they were not attending the services in the temple regardin bowing down. That is also the reason one 'leins' about who not to marry 'parshas aroyos' on mincha on yom kipppur.

My questions. Is that really what is supposed to be done on yom kippur. Today that would be frowned upon even on other days, 'boys watching girls dancing'. 
It says they went to find husbands. They were joined by the daughters of the king and kohen godol. Is that really the only way THEY  could find their husbands?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/how-to-handle-clothesline-for-my-cute-vort-questions

Comment: I'm sorry to see that you're unhappy with how posts you've made have been handled by the community. I think that you may have been expecting more of a blogging format than the community-based Q&A system that we have. I strongly recommend that you take a look at [our About page](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/about) for an overview of how we're different, at our [help] for more details, and specifically at [this page](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/editing) on how and why we have community-based editing.

Answer (score -2):

Have to give my answer since no one else does.
The question more or less contains the answer. During the year its wrong for boys to watch girls dancing. The satan is at work. Yom kippur is his only day 'off'. So then the boys can watch. Since it cannot be done on any other day therefore they had to allow it on yom kippur.
The king's daughter did not go there to find a shidduch so the meforshim ('kol bo') say.

I wonder does any dating go on today on yom kippur!